# JAVA - Recursive function to determine all prime factors of n

Tags: algorithm, recursion

What I have problems understanding is how can I write a recursive method that adds to the array, if I can only have ***n*** as parameter to my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look either like:

```
def factorize(n):
    factors= list()
    found= False
    t= 2
    while t*t <= n and not found:
        while (n % t) == 0:
            # divisible by 2
            factors.append(t)
            found= True
            n//= t
        t+= 1
    if found:
        factors.extend(factorize(n))
    else:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

factorize(3*5*5*7*7*31*101)
# --> [3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 31, 101]
```

Which is a naiive apporoach, to keep it simple. Or you allow some more (named) arguments to your recursive function, which would also allow passing a list. Like:

```
def factorize2(n, result=None, t=2):
    if result:
        factors= result
    else:
        factors= list()
    found= False
    while t*t <= n and not found:
        while (n % t) == 0:
            factors.append(t)
            found= True
            n//= t
        t+= 1
    if found:
        factorize2(n, factors, t+1)
    else:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

The basic difference is, that here you reuse the list the top level function created. This way you might give the garbabge collector a little less work (though in case of a factorization function this probably doesn't make much of a difference, but in other cases I think it does). The second point is, that you already tested some factors and don't have to retest them. This is why I pass t.

Of course this is still naiive. You can easily improve the performance, by avoiding the t*t < n check in each iteration and by just testing t if t is -1/1 mod 6 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You have two cases: base case and recursion case.  For your problem, the high-level logic looks like this:

```
if n is prime
    return array(n)   // return a one-element array
else {
    find a prime divisor, p
    // return an array of p and the factorisation of n/p
    return array(p, FACTORIZATION(n/p) )
}
```

Does that get you moving?  You'll need to know how to make and append to arrays in your chosen language, but those are implementation details.

Comment: SO i have to represent both cases, or do I just write the algorithm?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; a recursive function needs both cases.  You have to write the code.  I *think* the answer is "you do both".

Comment: Ok thank you, and what do you mean by array in your pseudocode? Does it mean append

Comment: The comment above explains that: you have to concatenate/append `p` to the array returned by the recursive call.  I strongly recommend that you work through a tutorial on recursion, in your preferred language; that should give you the particular concepts and techniques you need.

Comment: Thank yo very much!

Comment: And for find a prime divisor, p comment above, do I have to write n % i == 0 to find a divisor?

Comment: This is not a site to receive line-by-line tutorial help.  You should be able to look up how to determine a prime number in your chosen language -- there are many solutions available.  The needed code will be embedded in those solutions.

Comment: I know how to find a prime number as seen in my question, I just don't know where you got p from. I'm also not looking for the answer line-by-line.

Comment: I didn't detail that code, as you already have a function to find a prime divisor.  Whatever you found, I'm simply calling `p` for the purposes of the recursive algorithm.

Comment: This is a good start. Here is another hint: when you're checking for divisors, only check odd numbers past 2. In other words, check 2,3,5,7,9, etc. There's no need to check even numbers other than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to have in your toolbox is to not return an array, but rather a linked list.  That is a data structure where each piece of data links to the next, links to the next, and so on.  Factorization doesn't really show the power of it, but here it is anyways:

```
def factorize(n, start=2):
    i = start
    while i < n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return [i, factorize(n//i, i)]
        elif n < i*i:
            break
        i = i + 1
    if 1 < i:
        return [n, None]
    else:
        return None

print(factorize(3*5*5*7*7*31*101)) # [3, [5, [5, [7, [7, [31, [101, None]]]]]]]
```

The win with this approach is that it does not modify the returned data structure.  So if you're doing something like searching for an optimal path through a graph, you can track multiple next moves without conflict.  I find this particularly useful when modifying dynamic programming algorithms to actually find the best solution, rather than to report how good it is.

The one difficulty is that you wind up with a nested data structure.  But you can always flatten it as follows:

```
def flatten_linked_list (ll):
    answer = []
    while ll is not None:
        answer.append(ll[0])
        ll = ll[1]
    return answer

# prints [3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 31, 101]
print(flatten_linked_list( factorize(3*5*5*7*7*31*101) ))
```

Comment: If we have the second, `start`, parameter, we don't need the while loop.

Comment: @גלעדברקן No, we can write it as a loop or as recursion.  But Python makes recursion far slower.  So if both are easy, I pick the loop.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking language-specific, just in principle.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two recursive methods. The first has one parameter and uses a while loop to find a divisor, then uses divide and conquer to recursively query the factors for each of the two results of that division. (This method is more of an exercise since we can easily do this much more efficiently.) The second relies on a second parameter as a pointer to the current prime factor, which allows for a much more efficient direct enumeration.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(n){
  let a = ~~Math.sqrt(n)
  while (n % a)
    a--
  if (a < 2)
    return n == 1 ? [] : [n]
  let b = n / a 
  let [fa, fb] = [f(a), f(b)]
  return (fa.length > 1 ? fa : [a]).concat(
    fb.length > 1 ? fb : [b])
}

function g(n, d=2){
  if (n % d && d*d < n)
    return g(n, d == 2 ? 3 : d + 2)
  else if (d*d <= n)
    return [d].concat(g(n / d, d))
  return n == 1 ? [] : [n]
}

console.log(f(567))
console.log(g(12345))
```

Comment: For example, [10,10,1]....Total sum-Max element = 21-10=11, but the correct answer is 32 :(

Comment: @sdrtgghytui ah, my bad. I'll think about it.

Comment: @sdrtgghytui I think we can have a naive divide and conquer like 
`f(i, j) = min(A[k] + min(sum[i..k-1], sum[k+1..j]) + f(i, k - 1) + f(k + 1, j))`